# How to save form values in a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using simple modal to show a div with some form fields. The form is not to be submitted in the modal.  When the modal is closed, however, the values for the fields are lost.

What is a good way to keep the values that were entered in the fields after the modal window has closed?

I'm thinking about putting a 'Done' Button on the modal that will take those values and do something with them, but I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this problem in terms of making those values persist after the modal has closed. So in essence, the user closes the modal and then can submit the form if they chose, and the values from the modal will be posted.

Comment: Well the first step would be to determine what you want the values to do. A form without a submit button does nothing. You could read the values via jquery with `$(input).attr('value');` and store them in an array... but for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If when the modal window is closed, it posts back to the server, html input controls will not hold there values after the postback. Maybe you can implement a `VIEWSTATE` or the like for those controls so that they can do so.

If you showed some code, like your modal window setup, I could try to put some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('form').serialize()` and save the serialized form values in a variable when the modal window is closed.

You can also use `.serializeArray()` if you need a more digestible array of form values.

In other words, attach it to a close event for your modal (pseudo-code ahead):

```
var formValues;
Modal.onclose(function() {
  formValues = $('#modalform').serialize();
  // "do" something with formValues
});
```